# Getting the following Error on my Gatsby Project: Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Getting the following error on my Gatsby Project: Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321

Things I have tried:

- Removed and reinstalled node_modules
- Updated node_modules

```
  *
  38 |  * Let's warn if we find service workers in development.
  39 |  */
> 40 | if (`serviceWorker` in navigator) {
  41 |   navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
  42 |     if (registrations.length > 0)
  43 |       console.warn(
```